# Simple JDBC SQL Query returns an empty ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, jdbc

I have been trying to get a plugin I am working on to talk to my SQL database, creating tabels, and adding rows seems to work fine but simple SELECT queries are returning an empty ResultSet. The relevant code is below.

```
        queryL=
                "SELECT RATING"
                        + " FROM USERS"
                        + " WHERE UUID = '"
                        + UUID +"';";
        queryG=
                "SELECT RATING"
                        + " FROM " + Constants.serverName 
                        + "_USERS"
                        + " WHERE UUID = '"
                        + UUID +"';";
        try {
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(queryL);

            if (rs.next()){
                r.setLocalRating(rs.getInt(1));
            }else{
                r.setLocalRating(0);
                registerPlayer(UUID,false);
                Dungeon.getPlugin(Dungeon.class).log("Player new to server");
            }
            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try{
            stmt=con.createStatement();
            rs=stmt.executeQuery(queryG);
            if (rs.next()){
                r.setGlobalRating(rs.getInt(1));
            }else{
                r.setGlobalRating(0);
                registerPlayer(UUID,true);
                Dungeon.getPlugin(Dungeon.class).log("Player new to network");
            }
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As you can see if the ResultSet is empty (player does not yet exist in my database) I call registerPlayer. Register player then throws a duplicate entry for primary key error, so I know the table and the row I am looking for exist.

The following code shows the update queries used inside the registerPlayer method.

```
    if (global){
        query=
                "INSERT INTO"
                //+ Constants.dbName + "."
                + " USERS"
                + " VALUES ('"
                + UUID + "', 0)";

    }else{
        query=
                "INSERT INTO "
                //+ Constants.dbName + "."
                + Constants.serverName
                + "_USERS "
                + "VALUES ('"
                + UUID + "', 0)";
    }
```

Finally for completeness, the queries used for creating the tables

```
    String userLocalTable=
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " //+ Constants.dbName + "."
                    + Constants.serverName +
                    "_USERS " +
                    "(UUID varchar(36) NOT NULL, " +
                    "RATING int NOT NULL, " +
                    "PRIMARY KEY (UUID))";
    String userGlobalTable=
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + //Constants.dbName + "."
                    "USERS " +
                    "(UUID varchar(36) NOT NULL, " +
                    "RATING int NOT NULL, " +
                    "PRIMARY KEY (UUID))";
```

Any insight into my issue would be greatly appreciated, as far as I can tell the SELECT queries should not be returning empty ResultSets.

Comment: Do you happen to be using executeQuery or executeUpdate to run the inserts???

Comment: the updates run with executeUpdate(), but as far as I can tell they are working fine. The issue is the SELECTs returning nothing when I know that there is at-least 1 row.

Comment: What data type is UUID (in Java)?

Comment: my Java variable is a String, and the column in the database is defined as varchar(36)

Comment: I see nothing glaring. I'd look for differences in UUID (are you reading it from stdin...does it have a newline in it you don't expect?). Etc. My guess is UUID doesn't have in it what you think it has in it. Try printing it with System.out.printf("->%s<-", UUID) to see exactly what it has (the arrows will let you see whitespace)

Comment: The UUID variable is used in the SELECT, but the exact same variable is passed to the registerPlayer method.When it tries to insert a new row it errors due to duplicate key, so I am confident that the UUID value matches up.

However I will try your suggestion to confirm 100%

Comment: confirmed the UUID is proper

Comment: Sorry Kyle, them's my best guesses.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the attempt!

Comment: It is not related to your problem, but you really shouldn't concatenate values into a statement. Please use `PreparedStatement` and parameter placeholders. It protects you against SQL injection, and usually also has other benefits (code readability, statement caching, etc).

Comment: BTW: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server, it is not very common to tag both.

Comment: My mistake on the tags, I am using MySQL

Comment: [`UUID = "'; DROP DATABASE dungeon; --"`](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I am sorry not sure I follow, are you suggesting I drop the database on every run?

Comment: @KyleH: Lukas Eder is pointing out that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  If that UUID is passed to your code, your application will drop the `dungeon`table.  Imagine you've got your code working and you've got lots of lovely data in that table.  Someone comes along, enters that malicious UUID and boom! all your data is gone.  Do you want that to happen? Finally, as we're talking about SQL injection it would be remiss of me not to add the obligatory link to [this xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/327).

Comment: @LukeWoodward: Ahh ok, yeah I don't know why I didn't notice that haha. I have already adjusted my code to use PreparedStatement.

Although with the use of this database the user's do not actually have any actual control over the inputs. UUIDs are objects of Java UUID.class and I simply use the toString() method before accessing the database.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, turns out it was something obvious staring me in the face, QueryL's and QueryG's respective queries needed to be swapped.